# How to select a single radio option?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, radio-button

I can't select a single radio option. It's keeps selecting all radios

I created 4 radio option and I'm trying to select only 1 button, and it's keeps selecting all. I used pure html coding no JavaScript attached to it

Comment: Can you provide example ?

Comment: Welcome! Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), without any code nobody can help you

Comment: Maybe you're not naming them, `name="Somename"` is necessary to select only one.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the radio button on the html can only be selected only one, try to see documentation of html or w3school

Answer (score 1):

You're not naming them, `name="Somename"` is necessary to select only one option, input have to be named with same name.

[Reference here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_group)

```html
<div>
  <h1>Named inputs</h1>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Somename"> Option1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Somename"> Option2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Somename"> Option3</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Somename"> Option4</label>


  <h1>Not named inputs</h1>
  <label><input type="radio"> Option1</label>
  <label><input type="radio"> Option2</label>
  <label><input type="radio"> Option3</label>
  <label><input type="radio"> Option4</label>
</div>
```